# what is the dual of line (x=-y)

Tags: dual-cone

I encountered this question: Find the dual cone of $K = \{(x,y)|(x+y=0)\}$. To find the dual ($K^* = \{y \mid x'y \geq 0 \text{ for all }x \in K \}$), I did the following: 
\begin{align}
                     (x,-x)(y_1,y_2)'& \geq 0 \\
                         xy_1-xy_2 & \geq 0 \\
                         x(y_1-y_2) & \geq 0 \\
                           y_1 & \geq y_2
\end{align}

But the Dual of this cone is $\{(y_1,y_2) \mid y_1=y_2 \}$. Can you find out where is the mistake? Thanks!

Comment: It would help if you elaborated on how you went from $x(y_1 - y_2) \geq 0$ to $y_1 \geq y_2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have correctly deduced that $y_1 \geq y_2$.  You can also deduce that $y_1 \leq y_2$.  It follows that $y_1 = y_2$.  So, the dual cone of $K$ is 
$$
K^* = \{ (y_1,y_2) \mid y_1 = y_2\}.
$$

By the way, here is a useful fact: if $K$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^n$, the dual cone of $K$ is the subspace orthogonal to $K$.